# Is there a difference between velocity and drift velocity?

Tags: velocity

While I do know that VELOCITY is displacement in time ,I read something about the DRIFT VELOCITY of electrons. What is DRIFT VELOCITY?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is drift velocity? And how to find the equation for it?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/100952/what-is-drift-velocity-and-how-to-find-the-equation-for-it)

Comment: @JohnRennie - I agree, but the question you cite should perhaps be reopened - it seems odd to cite a duplicate that is a closed question... what do you think?

Comment: @tom: Your question is a perennial one on SE meta. There are arguments for and against linking to closed questions. E.g. closed questions can be reopened.

Comment: @tom: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6564/50583

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not show the slightest research effort, and is easily answered by, e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drift_velocity).

Comment: Still SHOUTING, I see. That is not a way to make friends on the internet. This point of etiquette goes back to the 1970's.

Comment: I wont shout anymore .Im sure to obey to points of etiqette from the 1970's @dmckee

Comment: @ACuriousMind : Im sorry about the question

Comment: @JohnRennie: I agree that both questions have the same answer .Im sorry about the question

Answer (score 1):

Drift velocity is the velocity attained by a particle because of an electric field. Because current is proportional to drift velocity, which in a resistive material is, in turn, proportional to the magnitude of an external electric field, Ohm's law can be explained in terms of drift velocity.

he definition of drift velocity can be understood by imagining the random motion of free electrons in a conductor. The free electrons in a conductor moves with random velocities and in random directions. When an electric field is applied across the conductor the randomly moving electrons are subjected to electrical forces along the direction of the field. Due to this field, the electrons do not give up their randomness of motion, but they will be shifting towards higher potential. That means the electrons will drift towards higher potential along with their random motions. Thus, every electron will have a net velocity towards the higher potential end of the conductor and this net velocity is referred as the drift velocity of electrons. Hopping you understand the definition of drift velocity. The current due to this drift movement of electrons inside an electrically stressed conductor, is known as drift current. It is needless to say that every current that flows through a conductor is drift current.

[[image] <sup>gsu.edu</sup>](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/ohmmic.html)

Comment: I would add that drift velocity is the overall average (mean) velocity of the electrons. It is implied in your answer, but could be made clearer perhaps